# MySQL make a two dimensional table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have to develop a bus timetable using sql, but I have no idea so far.
Now I have made a table with three columns which are `stop_id`, `run_id` and `time`. `run_id` is different for every bus line (dynamic), and `stop_id` is different for every bus line too, but I have already sorted in order.

How can I write a SQL to make a table whose first column shows stops, whose row is for every run, and content is time. For example

```
       |run7   |run5   |run8  |....
stop1  |15:00  |16:00  |17:00 |....
stop6  |15:02  |16:02  |17:02 |....
  .    | .     | .     | .    |....
  .    | .     | .     | .    |....
  .    | .     | .     | .    |....
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should think about what Instances you have:

- Bus Line: A busline can have several tours (e.g. Shelbyville to Springfield and Springfield to Shelbyville)

  - Tour: A tour can have several stops.
  - Tour_Stops: From one stop to another stop you have estimated time in minutes. Also you have a defined order on your stops (first railwaystation, then school, and then the park-road e.g)
  - Run: A run has a start-time and one route

So I would suggest the following data-model:

busline: ID, name
tour: ID, name, busline_id
tour_stops: ID, order, duration_to_next_stop, stop_id, route_id
run: starting_time, route_id

I think with this tables you are able to reuse a route again and a again.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for how to "pivot" the data.  Here is a blog that gives a solution, including a stored procedure that generates the necessary code.
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Answer (score -1):

just normalize these table. make 2 table

- table 1: having three cols-{ unique_id,stopid,run_id}
- table 2: having{unique_id,time}. here unique_id is foreign key to table 1.

Comment: The data is normalized